# What are different ways I can ship python module as a reusable module

Tags: python

In python we do pip install to install some external libraries, modules etc.
If i have to create a reusable python module that can be used by several different APIs in an enterprise, is there a known way to create this module and ship it so that consuming applications just install it somehow and import the module rather that taking the source code from a common repository, creating a local module out of it and then do a module import.

Can someone educate me with what best practices we have in python for this use case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flow is quite simple:

1. You create your lib.
2. You define `setup.py` file (versioning here is important).
3. You build your lib.
4. You upload it to a pypi server (either public or your private).
5. Other applications simply bump version and `pip install` from either public or your private pypi server (there is a flag in `pip` command tool to switch to other server).

You should start with learning either distutils or setuptools (my favourite) for points 2 and 3.

For a private pypi server you have to set it up. I've actually never done it by myself but I assume it can't be hard. Google `pypi server`.

Comment: distutils or setuptools?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I prefer setuptools but it's up to you.

Comment: I do to. I think you should mention that since they have different options.

Comment: If i don't use either public or private pyPI server then, is there any other way to install the .gz file that "python setup.py sdist" creates ?

Comment: I did pip install sample.tar.gz and it was able to install it correctly. How do I use the clases/functions inside now ? I am not able to import anything inside of what was packaged.

Comment: @Hary Yes, you `pip install package.tar.gz`. You import everything normally. If you have a `foo` module then you simply do `import foo`. Just remember to properly configure `setup.py` to include the module.

Comment: I have a package (directory) foo and under that i have a module name bar. Keeping that in mind, in my setup.py I have put packages = ['foo']. Is that what goes inside of packages or the name of the module.

Comment: @Hary You actually have to recursively include all subdirectories. Have a look at `find_packages` function in setuptools.